# Parse date string with single digit day e.g. 1-11-2017 as well as 12-11-2017

Tags: c#, datetime

So I have a date String coming in with the short date of today.
For Example "1-11-2017"

```
//Here i convert the HttpCookie to a String 
string DateView = Convert.ToString(CurrDay.Value);

//Here i convert the String to DateTime
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DateView, "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

After running the code I get the error:

> FormatExeption was unhandled by user code
>
> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: `dd` expects `01`. You want `d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this using yyyy-MM-dd instead of dd-MM-yyyy
(and later converting it to normal dates)
Becouse the var always was the day of today the day can be 1 and 2 digits

```
 CurrDay.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd" ); 

 // Convert String to DateTime
 dateFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(CurrDay.Value.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The comments below helped me find this solution,
Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 20):

`1-11-2017` is not in the format of `dd-MM-yyyy`, specifically the first part. Use `d-M-yyyy` instead which will use one digit day and month when the value is below 10 (ie. no 0 padding).

Test:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("1-11-2017", "d-M-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(myDate.ToString());
```

If you do not know if there will be 0 padding you can pass an array of acceptable formats, the parser will try each one in order they appear in the array.

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("1-11-2017", new string[]{"d-M-yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy"}, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/46zGLw)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This kind of solved the problem. The problem is. When the day of today enters 2 digits the system will no longer work. do you think you have a fix for this? if so I would really appreciate the help! EDIT: accidentally hit Enter

Comment: Sorry accidentally hit Enter

Comment: @SennedeValk but if you do not know if there will be 0 padding you can use the second solution provided which will try both with and without 0 padding.

Comment: It does sorry, Got the same error because of a different reason when testing my program with a 2 digit date.

Comment: @SennedeValk - no worries, glad you got it working. Please consider marking an answer once the 15 minute grace period has expired.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is this didn't work with I didn't realize because the old date was saved through the cookies so I actually didn't test 2 digit day. I will consider answering a little later next time. :D

Comment: @SennedeValk - no worries. By marking an answer I was referring to the checkmark next to the given answer. Once your question has been answered it is considered good etiquette to mark the best answer (in the opinion of the person who asked the question) using the checkmark.

Comment: error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'

Answer (score 2):

The Date format `dd`stands for `The day of the month, from 01 through 31.` You either supply it as `01-11-2017` or change your formatter to `d-MM-yyyy`.

Here's a reference to [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 0):

It's because `ParseExact` means you pass the format and the method expects the same date format to be passed as string, that's why you need to pass `d-MM-yyyy` instead of `dd-MM-yyyy`.

I you're not sure if the passed string will be with one digit or two then do the following:

```
string[] digits = DateView.split('-');
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(digits[2], digits[1], digits[0]);
```

You even can split using `/` instead, but you need to make sure the first digit is a day and the second is month, and so on.

My advice is pass ticks instead of string of datetime:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(numberOfTicks);
string valueAsStr = date.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value like below,

```
  string DateView = Convert.ToString("01-11-2017");
  DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DateView, "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```